# How to load a select box in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to populate a select box with some database values in cakephp. The array I get from the database query is as follows,

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [mst_division] => Array ( [mstDivisionID] => 1 [Division] => Sydney ) )
[1] => Array ( [mst_division] => Array ( [mstDivisionID] => 2 [Division] => Tokyo 3 ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [mst_division] => Array ( [mstDivisionID] => 3 [Division] => Osaka 9 ) ) 
)
```

I am a bit confused as to how I should load this to a select box. My PHP code is as shown below,

```
echo $this->Form->input('Division', array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => $divisions,
                        'selected' => 2)
                       );
```

And my html code is also shown below,

```
<div class="input select"><label for="MemberDivision">Division</label><select      name="data[Member][Division]" id="MemberDivision">
</optgroup>
<option value="Division">Sydney</option>
<optgroup label="mst_division">
<optgroup label="1">
</optgroup>
<option value="Division">Tokyo 3</option>
<optgroup label="mst_division">
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="2">
</optgroup>
<option value="Division">Osaka 9</option>
<option value="mstDivisionID">3</option>
<optgroup label="mst_division">
</optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: use $divisions = $this->ModelName->find('list');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->set('divisions',$this->Model->find('list'));
```

try it , i hope it will work.